# .htaccess redirect if request method is post

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-302

I have a wordpress site that for various reasons needs a 302 redirect if a certain page is hit with a POST request, any other request should action as usual (ie GET requests). All the methods I have tried however simply perform the redirect regardless of the request method.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
Redirect 302 /gallery /wp-json/posts
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the syntax from two entirely different, and competing modules there: mod_rewrite (RewriteCond) and mod_redirect (Redirect), as there's no connection between the two mod_redirect will always redirect, as there's no condition. Similarly you have a condition for a mod_rewrite redirection, but not the actual Redirection directive (RewriteRule). Anyway of the two modules use just use mod_rewrite eg.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule /?gallery /wp-json/posts  [L]
```

Comment: That makes sense, probably should have spotted that one. Still having issues now in that the htaccess is ignoring the RewriteCond. Possibly due to the position of this within the base wordpress rewrites?